# Is there a way for PHP to remain in the same directory between multiple backtick commands?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am planning to execute an operation using the backtick operator in a foreach loop. I want to change to the desired directory before the loop, and then iterate without needing to change the directory back.

The following simple test seems to show that you can not stay in the same directory between operations:

```
$output=`pwd`."<br />";
$output.=`cd ~/domains && pwd`."<br />";
$output.=`pwd`;
echo $output;
die;

// output

home-path
home-path/domains
home-path
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or should I  just `cd` to the directory every time I execute in the foreach loop?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: http://php.net/chdir

Comment: Sounds like you should just use the PHP functions [`chdir`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and [`getcwd`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: @PedroLobito I'll be looping through a list and downloading files to a directory. I'd like to `cd` to that directory and then `wget` all the files

Comment: @Kurt looks like this could work. Will test and see. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks for getcwd too.

Comment: `chdir` worked. Feel dumb that I was looking for shell solution instead of a PHP one.  Maybe this is a noob question (I'm a bit noob): do I wait for an answer, answer my own question, or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

`chdir` was the winner! Modified my test and it works fine:

```
$output=getcwd()."<br />";
chdir('home-path/domains');
$output.=getcwd()."<br />";
$output.=`pwd`;
echo $output;
die;

// output

home-path
home-path/domains
home-path/domains
```